# Maintaining banners in GAE app

Tags: image, google-app-engine

I'm planning to deploy a GAE app and a question comes to mind: If there's a set of banners in my pages, What's the most efficient way to maintain such images/swf files outside the app itself? The goal is not to have to do re-deploy the app only because some graphic files change.

My first intention is to use Java, but I'm open to switch to Go or Python if it makes a difference in this matter.

Comment: How about hosting them on Amazon S3 or a similar platform and just linking to them from your app?

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you're going to program it. If the banners going to be part of your static files then you will have to redeploy every time you want to change the banner. But if you're going to implement it in a dynamic kind of way then there is no need to redeploy unless there is an update. You can achieve that by adding the functionality of changing the banner within your app (uploading new banner, or changing URLs for example) or store your banners in external providers and override them.

If you're starting now, I would suggest you to go with [Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was hoping not to implement a banner administration, but to use something the platform supported (such as sftp, a web interface or even Picasa), otherwise I guess I'll store them in the Database. Would you elaborate on why to choose Python over Java ?

Comment: @xain IMHO I think Python is less noisy as a language to begin with compare to Java. The dev environment is lighter since you don't have to run Eclipse. But in the end you will have to see that on your own. In both languages you can achieve everything, so I'll suggest you before you decide, complete the Getting Started in both languages without going into many details, just to get an idea how GAE works.

Answer (score 0):

You could host the banner SWFs on any service that provides a URL.  Then you can just change the file that the URL points to.

If you want to host them on App Engine, then you probably want to use the Blobstore.  Check out the Blobstore API.